# Java 7 Watch Service ENTRY_CREATE triggered before file is written

Tags: java, java-7, watchservice

I have a watch service watching a directory. Once files are created, I'm processing the directory and updating a tree view.

This works fine on `ENTRY_DELETE`, but sometimes (not always) when a `WatchEvent` of `ENTRY_CREATE` occurs, the file has not yet been written to the disk.

I've confirmed this by creating a `new File()` of the directory the watch service is registered to along with the path of the file and checking the `exists()` method, so it seems that the OS is triggering the create event before the file is actually created.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012487/java-watchservice-on-windows-informing-of-folder-creation-before-contents-have-b?rq=1) appears to be the same issue, but from the folder's point of view.

Any way I can work around this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956262/java-watchservice-gets-informed-before-content-is-copied) -- looks like you're suffering from the same problem.

Comment: It does - I'll leave this up for a bit in case any better solutions emerge though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The event is triggered when a file is created. The file needs to be created before it can be written to. A file doesn't simply appear once it is fully written, it appears once it is created.

What you can do is once you get the creation event:

- Create a [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object to point to the file
- Create a [java.nio.channels.FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) for random access using [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) with `rw` mode (so read & write access)
- [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28%29) the channel. This will block until the file is free for read/write access (read the more general [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28long,%20long,%20boolean%29) method for more info)
- When the lock is acquired, your file was released by the process that wrote the file

A simplified example:

```
File lockFile = new File( "file_to_lock" );
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile( lockFile, "rw" ).getChannel( );
channel.lock( );
```

Comment: I can only award the bounty in 20 hours, I'll do so then.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, I added few seconds delay once the event is created before processing. Since Other application used to write the file and it used to take couple of seconds to flush the content and release the file.

Comment: Problem is, I need to keep it as responsive as possible so I'm looking for a way where I minimize the delay.